# How to create my personal pipe in base R using the new native pipe and pipebind

Tags: r, performance, pipe

I want to be able to use `>>` instead of `|>. =>` to convert approach 3 into 4 below while preserving/improving performance.

```
Sys.setenv("_R_USE_PIPEBIND_"=TRUE)
library(magrittr)
xt <- extract <- `[`; dv <- divide <- `/`; num <- `as.numeric`; y <- 5000
txt <- paste0(scales::label_comma(accuracy = 1)(rpois(2,y)))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(

txt %>% sub(",", "", .) %>% num() %>% .[2]/2 - y*0.5, #approach 1

txt |> (\(.) sub(",", "", .) )() |> num() |> (\(.) .[2]/2 - y*0.5)(), #approach 2

txt |>. => sub(",", "", .) |> num() |> . => xt(.,2) |> . => dv(.,2) - y*0.5, #approach 3

#txt >> sub(",", "", .) |> num() >> xt(.,2) >> dv(.,2) - y*0.5, #approach 4

times = 100L

)

Unit: microseconds
    
     expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
approach 1 9.701 10.3510 24.29601 31.6005 33.851  53.402   100
approach 2 7.901 10.1005 23.33513 29.9020 31.902 128.901   100
approach 3 6.701  7.3010 16.44111  9.0010 28.950  36.501   100
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I'm still learning more about `=>`, but I believe it is not going to be maintained, preferring the `_` which is similar to magrittr's `.` operator. The biggest differences are that `_` can only be used once and must be in a named parameter, such as `txt |> sub(",", "", x=_) |> as.numeric() |> ...`

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans. We never know the future. In my case, I found approach 4 more useful than `_` and with higher performance than the other shown approaches. So, any thoughts on how to implement my personal pipe would be much appreciated.

Comment: No, I don't. Implementing a "pipe" *efficiently* is likely to take a lot of work and be prone to corner-cases and syntactic mis-interpretation, etc. magrittr's `%>%` took a couple of iterations (and a rewrite) to get it to where it is today, and it does not (in basic situations) quite match the base pipe in raw performance, assuming all of `|>`'s differences are acceptable. I understand your plight, but I foresee too many problems to try to play with this science-experiment. I wish you luck, though!